# multiple bannerview in single UIViewController - Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
 {
 [self AdRequest1];
 [self AdRequest2];
 }


 -(void)AdRequest1
 {

 CGRect frame = baseView1.frame;

 int yPos = frame.origin.y +frame.size.height;

 bannerView1 =[[GADBannerView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, yPos , scrollViewMain.frame.size.width, 50)];
 bannerView1.adUnitID = @"/1028307/Calendar-Banner-320x50"; // 320x50 size bannerAd
 bannerView1.rootViewController = self;
 bannerView1.delegate = self;
 [bannerView1 loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];
 bannerView1.tag = 111;
 [viewDetailAll addSubview:bannerView1];

 }

 -(void)AdRequest2
 {

 CGRect frame = baseView2.frame;

 int yPos = frame.origin.y +frame.size.height;

 bannerView2 =[[GADBannerView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, yPos , scrollViewMain.frame.size.width, 250)];
 bannerView2.adUnitID = @"1028307/Calendar-300x250"; // 320x250 size bannerAd
 bannerView2.rootViewController = self;
 bannerView2.delegate = self;
 [bannerView2 loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];
 bannerView2.tag = 222;
 [viewDetailAll addSubview:bannerView2];

 }

 - (void)adView:(GADBannerView *)view didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(GADRequestError *)error;
 {
 if (bannerView1.tag == 111) {
 bannerView1.hidden =YES;
 NSLog(@"Failed to receive ad with error: %@", [error localizedFailureReason]);
 [self AdRequest1];
 }


 if (bannerView2.tag == 222) {
 bannerView2.hidden =YES;
 NSLog(@"Failed to receive ad with error: %@", [error localizedFailureReason]);
 [self AdRequest2];
 }
 }

 - (void)adViewDidReceiveAd:(GADBannerView *)view;
 {
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void)
 {
 if (bannerView1.tag == 111) {

 bannerView1.hidden =NO;
 bannerView1.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
 NSLog(@"Ad Received bannerView1");

 //Above baseview1
 }

 if (bannerView2.tag == 222) {
 bannerView2.hidden =NO;
 bannerView2.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
 NSLog(@"Ad Received bannerView2");
 //Above baseview2

 }
 });
 }
```

i want to add 2 BannerAdView in one UIviewController of differentSize.
Here is my code the Ad erceived but cant able to position the 2Ad in expected position. plz help me

1st banner size 320*50
2nd banner size 320*250

and another issue is. if a Ad request received or failed both the banner request triggerd. i seperate it by tag but cant able to do.

Comment: its means your UI is not updated

Comment: no, Ad is coming in my UI, but there were 2 problems

Comment: @ThreeCoins 1st issue:   i cant able to fix the Adview in expected frame.  view1 height 100, above this view1 bannerAd1, and Below view1 BannerAd2 want to come

Comment: are you get the correct frame coordiante `CGRect frame = baseView2.frame;`

Comment: yes @ThreeCoins iam getting correct frame only. but cant able tofix it were i want. and **how can i know that bannerview1 request and bannerview2 request** i used **tag** but not working

Comment: try once in viewwillappear

Comment: @ThreeCoins or ant body Help me in this issue

Comment: can you print once `baseView2.frame` and `baseView1.frame`